# 'In a two variable function, $x$ and $y$ must be independent'.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

In my textbook it says, a function '$F(x,y)$ is a function of two variables if $x$ and $y$ are independent'.

However, if $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary elements, the assertion $F(x,y)=xy$ (For example) can still be used to define the function especially as the function $F$ can be applied to any variables we wish.

I understand that we need to independent variables $x,y$ in order to be able to make the full set of ordered triples of the form $(x,y,z)$ where $z=f(x,y)$, (the graph of $F$) but how does this definition affect the definition of $F$? Is it simply that there is a single variable function $g$ that could be defined as $g(x)=F(x,y)$.

Answer (score 3):

All the textbook is saying is that if you made one variable a function of the other, say $y = g(x)$, then you'd have a function of one variable $x$ given by $F(x, g(x))$ rather than a function of two variables.

Comment: but $F$ is multi-varied? Is it saying that $g(x)=F(x,g(x))$ and hence $g$ is single variable?